# crontab не выполняет скрипт полностью

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

Я сделал скрипт для выполнения резервного копирование базы данных.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
STORAGE_NAME=folder-backup
BACKUP_NAME=$(date +%y_%m_%d).gz
date
echo "Backing up MongoDB database to storage: $STORAGE_NAME"
echo "Dumping MongoDB $DB database to compressed archive"
mongodump -u user -p 1234 --authenticationDatabase admin --archive=/backup/tmp_dump.gz --gzip
echo "Copying compressed archive to storage: $STORAGE_NAME"
gsutil cp /backup/tmp_dump.gz gs://$STORAGE_NAME/$BACKUP_NAME
echo "Cleaning up compressed archive"
rm /backup/tmp_dump.gz
echo "Backup complete!"
```

Когда я запускаю вручную его, он работает и файл резервной копии отправляется.

```
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: -backup
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive
2019-09-09T06:03:23.513-0400    writing admin.system.indexes to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.557-0400    done dumping admin.system.indexes (3 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:23.557-0400    writing config.system.indexes to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.596-0400    done dumping config.system.indexes (2 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:23.596-0400    writing admin.system.users to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.654-0400    done dumping admin.system.users (2 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:23.654-0400    writing admin.system.version to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.712-0400    done dumping admin.system.version (2 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:23.712-0400    writing test.AccountService to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.722-0400    writing test.Settings to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.732-0400    writing test._User to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:23.747-0400    writing test.NotificationSettings to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:24.112-0400    done dumping test._User (2506 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:24.112-0400    writing test._Session to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:24.131-0400    done dumping test.NotificationSettings (2240 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:24.131-0400    writing test._PushStatus to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:24.135-0400    done dumping test.Settings (2522 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:24.135-0400    writing test.TaxEvent to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:24.152-0400    done dumping test.AccountService (4887 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:24.153-0400    writing test.fs.chunks to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:24.392-0400    done dumping test._Session (2139 documents)
2019-09-09T06:03:24.392-0400    writing test.fs.files to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:03:24.555-0400    [........................]  test.fs.files  0/90  (0.0%)
2019-09-09T06:03:24.555-0400    [########################]  test.fs.files  90/90  (100.0%)                                                                                      
2019-09-09T06:03:25.322-0400    done dumping test.TaxEvent (217 documents)                                                                                                      
2019-09-09T06:03:25.322-0400    writing test.CalendarEvent to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:03:25.333-0400    done dumping test._PushStatus (348 documents)                                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:03:25.333-0400    writing test.UserPurchase to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                      
2019-09-09T06:03:25.345-0400    done dumping test.fs.files (90 documents)                                                                                                       
2019-09-09T06:03:25.345-0400    writing test.EventKnowledge to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                    
2019-09-09T06:03:25.356-0400    done dumping test.fs.chunks (122 documents)                                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:03:25.356-0400    writing test.KnowledgeWebsite to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                  
2019-09-09T06:03:25.478-0400    done dumping test.CalendarEvent (60 documents)                                                                                                  
2019-09-09T06:03:25.478-0400    writing test._SCHEMA to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                           
2019-09-09T06:03:25.518-0400    done dumping test.EventKnowledge (43 documents)                                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:03:25.518-0400    writing test.News to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                              
2019-09-09T06:03:25.553-0400    done dumping test.UserPurchase (45 documents)                                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:03:25.553-0400    writing test.objectlabs-system.admin.collections to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                               
2019-09-09T06:03:25.565-0400    done dumping test.KnowledgeWebsite (26 documents)                                                                                               
2019-09-09T06:03:25.565-0400    writing test.objectlabs-system to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:03:25.643-0400    done dumping test._SCHEMA (13 documents)                                                                                                        
2019-09-09T06:03:25.643-0400    writing test._GlobalConfig to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:03:25.711-0400    done dumping test.News (5 documents)                                                                                                            
2019-09-09T06:03:25.711-0400    writing test._Installation to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:03:25.753-0400    done dumping test.objectlabs-system.admin.collections (3 documents)                                                                             
2019-09-09T06:03:25.753-0400    writing test._Role to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                             
2019-09-09T06:03:25.806-0400    done dumping test._GlobalConfig (1 document)                                                                                                    
2019-09-09T06:03:25.824-0400    done dumping test.objectlabs-system (1 document)                                                                                                
2019-09-09T06:03:25.863-0400    done dumping test._Installation (0 documents)                                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:03:25.863-0400    done dumping test._Role (0 documents)                                                                                                           
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
Copying file:///backup/tmp_dump.gz [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...                                                                                                   
| [1 files][ 13.4 MiB/ 13.4 MiB]                                                                                                                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/13.4 MiB.                                                                                                                                    
Cleaning up compressed archive                                                                                                                                                  
Backup complete!
```

Я решил сделать задачу.

```
* * * * * /mongo_backup.sh >> /mongo_backup.log
```

В файле `mongo_backup.log` записывается

```
Mon Sep  9 05:57:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
Mon Sep  9 05:58:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
Mon Sep  9 05:59:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
Mon Sep  9 06:00:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
Mon Sep  9 06:01:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
Mon Sep  9 06:02:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup
```

В файле `mongo_backup.log` отсутствуют строки

```
Copying file:///backup/tmp_dump.gz [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...                                                                                                   
| [1 files][ 13.4 MiB/ 13.4 MiB]                                                                                                                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/13.4 MiB.                                                                                                                                    
Cleaning up compressed archive                                                                                                                                                  
Backup complete!
```

И он отсутствует в моей корзине.

Почему так происходит? В ручную скрипт отрабатывает хорошо и файл резервной копии базы данный отправляется, в через `crontab` падает на отправки.

```
Mon Sep  9 06:18:01 EDT 2019                                                                                                                                                    
Backing up MongoDB database to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                       
Dumping MongoDB  database to compressed archive                                                                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:18:03.950-0400    writing admin.system.indexes to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'  
2019-09-09T06:18:03.990-0400    done dumping admin.system.indexes (3 documents)                                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:18:03.990-0400    writing config.system.indexes to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                  
2019-09-09T06:18:04.030-0400    done dumping config.system.indexes (2 documents)                                                                                                
2019-09-09T06:18:04.030-0400    writing admin.system.users to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:04.087-0400    done dumping admin.system.users (2 documents)                                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:18:04.087-0400    writing admin.system.version to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:18:04.144-0400    done dumping admin.system.version (2 documents)                                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:18:04.144-0400    writing test.AccountService to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                    
2019-09-09T06:18:04.152-0400    writing test.Settings to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                          
2019-09-09T06:18:04.160-0400    writing test._User to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                             
2019-09-09T06:18:04.175-0400    writing test.NotificationSettings to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                              
2019-09-09T06:18:04.567-0400    done dumping test.AccountService (4887 documents)                                                                                               
2019-09-09T06:18:04.567-0400    writing test._Session to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                          
2019-09-09T06:18:04.574-0400    done dumping test.Settings (2522 documents)                                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:04.575-0400    writing test._PushStatus to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                       
2019-09-09T06:18:04.642-0400    done dumping test.NotificationSettings (2240 documents)                                                                                         
2019-09-09T06:18:04.642-0400    writing test.TaxEvent to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                          
2019-09-09T06:18:04.652-0400    done dumping test._User (2506 documents)                                                                                                        
2019-09-09T06:18:04.652-0400    writing test.fs.chunks to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'
2019-09-09T06:18:04.855-0400    done dumping test.TaxEvent (217 documents)                                                                                                      
2019-09-09T06:18:04.855-0400    writing test.fs.files to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                          
2019-09-09T06:18:04.951-0400    done dumping test._PushStatus (348 documents)                                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:18:04.951-0400    writing test.CalendarEvent to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:04.955-0400    [#######################.]  test.fs.chunks  119/122  (97.5%)                                                                                    
2019-09-09T06:18:04.955-0400    done dumping test._Session (2139 documents)                                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:04.955-0400    writing test.UserPurchase to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                      
2019-09-09T06:18:04.982-0400    [########################]  test.fs.chunks  122/122  (100.0%)                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:18:05.958-0400    done dumping test.fs.files (90 documents)                                                                                                       
2019-09-09T06:18:05.958-0400    writing test.EventKnowledge to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                    
2019-09-09T06:18:05.969-0400    done dumping test.fs.chunks (122 documents)                                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:05.969-0400    writing test.KnowledgeWebsite to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                  
2019-09-09T06:18:05.988-0400    done dumping test.UserPurchase (45 documents)                                                                                                   
2019-09-09T06:18:05.988-0400    writing test._SCHEMA to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                           
2019-09-09T06:18:06.148-0400    done dumping test.CalendarEvent (60 documents)                                                                                                  
2019-09-09T06:18:06.148-0400    writing test.News to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                              
2019-09-09T06:18:06.163-0400    done dumping test._SCHEMA (13 documents)                                                                                                        
2019-09-09T06:18:06.163-0400    writing test.objectlabs-system.admin.collections to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                               
2019-09-09T06:18:06.175-0400    done dumping test.EventKnowledge (43 documents)                                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:18:06.175-0400    writing test.objectlabs-system to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                 
2019-09-09T06:18:06.188-0400    done dumping test.KnowledgeWebsite (26 documents)                                                                                               
2019-09-09T06:18:06.188-0400    writing test._GlobalConfig to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:06.299-0400    done dumping test.News (5 documents)                                                                                                            
2019-09-09T06:18:06.299-0400    writing test._Installation to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                     
2019-09-09T06:18:06.349-0400    done dumping test.objectlabs-system.admin.collections (3 documents)                                                                             
2019-09-09T06:18:06.349-0400    writing test._Role to archive '/backup/tmp_dump.gz'                                                                                             
2019-09-09T06:18:06.372-0400    done dumping test.objectlabs-system (1 document)                                                                                                
2019-09-09T06:18:06.378-0400    done dumping test._GlobalConfig (1 document)                                                                                                    
2019-09-09T06:18:06.449-0400    done dumping test._Role (0 documents)                                                                                                           
2019-09-09T06:18:06.449-0400    done dumping test._Installation (0 documents)                                                                                                   
Copying compressed archive to storage: folder-backup                                                                                                                        
/mongo_backup.sh: line 10: gsutil: command not found
```

Comment: `* * * * * /mongo_backup.sh >> /mongo_backup.log  2>&1` измените строку, что бы перехватывать поток ошибок при выполнение, после запуска приложите лог выполнения в вопрос.

Comment: @PotroNik Добавил, получаю ошибку `/mongo_backup.sh: line 10: gsutil: command not found`. Но почему он работает когда его запускаешь в ручную?

Comment: Скорее всего это из за переменных окружений, укажите полный путь до `gsutil` найти можно командой `whereis gsutil` вероятнее всего это /usr/bin/gsutil, либо укажите переменные окружения в задании cron.

Comment: @PotroNik Вы совершенно правы.

Comment: @PotroNik Но я все еще не могу понять, почему он вручную запускается, а через крон нет. Если я не указал полный путь, то и когда вручную запускал получал бы ошибку

Comment: Когда вы проходите авторизацию пользователем, у вас подгружается профиль и переменные окружения `PATH` посмотреть можно `echo $PATH` в кроне же переменные окружения задаются в файле с заданием, `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`, но это необязательный параметр и часто пропускается при настройке.

Comment: @PotroNik Теперь я все понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Резюмирую ответ из комментариев:

1. Для анализа проблем с запуском задания в крон, необходимо перехватывать поток stderr и записывать в лог сделать это можно следующим образом:*

   ```
   * * * * * /mongo_backup.sh >> /mongo_backup.log 2>&1
   ```
2. В заданиях cron завести привычку указывать переменные окружения и оболочку*

   ```
   SHELL=/bin/bash
   PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   MAILTO=user
   HOME=/home/user
   ```

   1. Возможно не указывать переменные окружения, а указывать в скрипте абсолютные пути до исполняемых программ

**Отступление:** при запуске скрипта каждую минуту рекомендуется обезопаситься от множественного выполнения командой `flock -w0 /var/run/1.lock /mongo_backup.sh` для задания cron будет по аналогии:

```
* * * * * flock -w0 /var/run/mongo_backup.lock /mongo_backup.sh 2>&1 >> /mongo_backup.log
```

Сейчас на процесс создания бэкапа уходит не много времени, но при увеличении объема данных или в связи с нагрузкой на оборудование архивация может не закончиться за отведенную минуту и произойдет повторный запуск.